# PDO MySQL insert multiple rows using select

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a table for storing people following others and another one for storing who has a certain book.

This is what I can do:

**List users who follow $userid**

```
$bookid = '000016';
$userid = '0000000000000156';
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT FOLLOW.USER_ID FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID = ?");
        $stmt -> execute(array($userid));       
        while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $output[] = $row;
            $response["success"] = 1;
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }
```

**List users who has $bookid**

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT USERS_BOOKS.USERID FROM USERS_BOOKS WHERE USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID = ?");
    $stmt -> execute(array($bookid));       
    while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $output2[] = $row;
        $response["success"] = 1;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response["success"] = 0;
}
```

Now I want to insert those into a new table who follow $userid and has $bookid. This is what I tried with different versions:

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO NOTI_COMPLETE2 (USERID_OWNER, USERID_COMPLETER, BOOKID)
        SELECT FOLLOW.USERID FROM FOLLOW
        LEFT JOIN USERS_BOOKS ON USERS_BOOKS.USERID = FOLLOW.USERID
        WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID = ? AND USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID = ?, ?, ?");
        $query_params = array($userid, $bookid, $userid, $bookid);  
    $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    $response["success"] = 1;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

So the result should look like this

```
ID, USERID_OWNER, USERID_COMPLETER, BOOKID
01, 000000000001, 0000000000000156, 000016
01, 000000000011, 0000000000000156, 000016
01, 000000000078, 0000000000000156, 000016
01, 000000000105, 0000000000000156, 000016
```

Meaning the table includes those USERID_OWNERs who follow USERID_COMPLETER and have BOOKID.

This throws an error (that's irrelevant I guess, because who knows how to do this, sees the problem).

Comment: You have only one column selected while in the insert command you have 3 , you need to select the same number of columns as that in select.

Answer (score 0):

You missed  **VALUES ('','','')**  and it should have exactly 3 columns fetched from your SELECT statement,

As I am not sure about  USERID_COMPLETER. You have to place the exact `'table-name'.'column-name'` there

```
  INSERT INTO NOTI_COMPLETE2 (`USERID_OWNER`, `USERID_COMPLETER`, `BOOKID`)
    VALUES ( SELECT FOLLOW.USERID, FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID, USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID FROM FOLLOW
            LEFT JOIN USERS_BOOKS ON USERS_BOOKS.USERID = FOLLOW.USERID
            WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID = ? AND USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID = ?);
```

Comment: USERID_COMPLETER is $userid. I don't understand: you select 3 columns, but then there is ?,? at the end... It's not working btw: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens[]`

Comment: These are trivial things. I copied it from your code only, how would I know your WHERE clause condition

Comment: I thought it was obvious as the second parameter in the INSERT INTO was USERID_COMPLETER, while the respective parameter in the array was $userid. Also, I don't need VALUES ('','',''). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO NOTI_COMPLETE2 (USERID_OWNER, USERID_COMPLETER, BOOKID)
     SELECT FOLLOW.USER_ID, ?, ?, ? FROM FOLLOW
            LEFT JOIN USERS_BOOKS ON USERS_BOOKS.USERID = FOLLOW.USER_ID
            WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID = ? AND USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID = ?");
            $query_params = array($userid, $bookid, $userid, $bookid);  
        $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        $response["success"] = 1;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```